# How do I carve a text shape or "negative space" into an object?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, text

I have a logo design that I'm trying to re-create digitally. I want to situate the company name in front of a vector design (a wheel) and cut-away from the wheel in the shape of the text so there is separation or "padding" in between elements. The text should "eat away" at the surrounding element in the shape of itself.

I know I could create a regular stroke, convert to outlines, align it outside and make it 6-8pts, but I want this logo to be able to go on various backgrounds and be embroidered on shirts such that the area around the text is actually negative space and doesn't require that the stroke colour match whatever it's being printed or placed on.

I just tried making a copy of my text > creating outlines > object -- path -- outline stroke > and then using minus front to carve out the shape, but minus front takes too much detail away from the middle area. It's a wheel and it completely erases the spoke elements rather than "shaving" them.

Thanks!

Comment: So, my only issue with this being marked as a duplicate is that the linked answer only provides 1/2 of the solution to my question. If I delete the stroke, that still leaves the original shape behind the text intact, doesn't it? Leaving me with the same problem I started with where I need the "background" shape to be shaved to the shape of the (former) stroke/text.

Comment: If you select all, expand, then use Pathfinder > Merge the stroke will be cut from everything. This one is similar and may help as well: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48900/removing-a-section-of-a-stroked-path-in-illustrator?rq=1